# Redirect website to new location, except for some folders

Tags: .htaccess, bots

I'm trying to redirect my websites content for bots, however I wish to keep some folders as is. I came up with this, however, only **snapshots** and **blog** folders work properly:

```
RewriteEngine on

# RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebook|bot) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (chrome) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/3rdpt
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/snapshots
RewriteRule ^ /snapshots/$1index.html [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

Could you please give me a hint ?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you access other folders?

Comment: redirects to /snapshots/index.html

Comment: Uhm... I'm really sorry. Seems it's working fine ^^ I was barking at the wrong tree (was looking in a wrong column in inspect).